# SQL Query - NOT in

Tags: sql-server

I got this SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_LEAN_GetAllActivityTest] @SearchParam NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@StatusID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT LEAN_Activity.ID
        ,LEAN_Activity.Activity
        ,SUBSTRING(LEAN_Activity.Description, 1, 80) + '...' AS [Description]
        ,LEAN_Activity.Participants
        ,LEAN_Activity.DATE
        ,LEAN_Company_Site.Site AS Location
        ,LEAN_Area.Area AS Område
        ,dbo.ReturnRetValName(MedarbejderSAP.MedarbejderNr) AS NAME
        ,LEAN_Aktivity_Priority.Priority AS Prioritet
    FROM LEAN_Activity
    INNER JOIN LEAN_Company_Site ON LEAN_Activity.Site = LEAN_Company_Site.ID
    INNER JOIN LEAN_Area ON LEAN_Activity.Area = LEAN_Area.ID
    INNER JOIN MedarbejderSAP ON LEAN_Activity.ProcessOwner = MedarbejderSAP.MedarbejderNr
    INNER JOIN LEAN_Aktivity_Priority ON LEAN_Activity.Priority = LEAN_Aktivity_Priority.ID
    INNER JOIN LEAN_Activity_Action ON LEAN_Activity.ID = LEAN_Activity_Action.ActivityID
    INNER JOIN LEAN_Aktivity_Status ON LEAN_Activity_Action.STATUS = LEAN_Aktivity_Status.ID
    WHERE (
            Lean_Activity.[ID] LIKE @SearchParam
            OR Lean_Activity.[Site] LIKE @SearchParam
            OR Lean_Activity.[Area] LIKE @SearchParam
            OR Lean_Activity.[ProcessOwner] LIKE @SearchParam
            OR Lean_Activity.[Activity] LIKE @SearchParam
            OR Lean_Activity.[Description] LIKE @SearchParam
            OR Lean_Activity.[Date] LIKE @SearchParam
            )
        AND (@StatusID IS NULL)
        OR (LEAN_Aktivity_Status.ID = @StatusID)
    ORDER BY LEAN_Activity.ID ASC
END
```

1 of the innerjoin tables are LEAN_Activity_Action. This table contains data like:

```
 ID ActivityID  Status  PlanDate    RealDate    SignedBy
 4  4           1       2014-11-27  NULL        10035002
14  4           2       2014-12-17  2015-01-14  10035002
31  4           3       2015-01-27  NULL        10035002
153 4           4       2014-11-27  2015-01-14  10035002
419 4           9       2014-11-27  NULL        10035002
```

(Any combinations are possible in the LEAN_Activity_Action table.)

and not I want to modify it so if table LEAN_Activity_Action contains a record for the ActivityID where

```
Status = 4 AND RealDate = NULL
```

the LEANActivity should not be included in the result.

How?

Comment: What about adding it to the `where`? Since you know the expression to use already, what is the problem?

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` in this situation.
Change `INNER JOIN activity_action` to

```
    CROSS APPLY(select * from activity_action where activity.ID = activityID and 
not exists
    (select * from activity_action where activity.ID = activityID and Status = 4 
and 
RealDate is NULL)) as activity_action
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_LEAN_GetAllActivity]
@SearchParam NvarChar(50),
@StatusID int

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT *    
FROM(   

SELECT DISTINCT LEAN_Activity.ID, LEAN_Activity.Activity, SUBSTRING(LEAN_Activity.Description, 1,80) + '...' AS [Description], 
LEAN_Activity.Participants, LEAN_Activity.Date, LEAN_Company_Site.Site AS Location, 
LEAN_Area.Area AS Område, dbo.ReturnRetValName(MedarbejderSAP.MedarbejderNr) AS Name, LEAN_Aktivity_Priority.Priority AS Prioritet
, (select count(*) from LEAN_Activity_Action where LEAN_Activity_Action.ActivityID = LEAN_Activity.ID and status = 4 and realdate is not null) as status

FROM            LEAN_Activity INNER JOIN
                     LEAN_Company_Site ON LEAN_Activity.Site =     LEAN_Company_Site.ID INNER JOIN
                     LEAN_Area ON LEAN_Activity.Area = LEAN_Area.ID INNER JOIN
                     MedarbejderSAP ON LEAN_Activity.ProcessOwner = MedarbejderSAP.MedarbejderNr INNER JOIN
                     LEAN_Aktivity_Priority ON LEAN_Activity.Priority = LEAN_Aktivity_Priority.ID INNER JOIN
                     LEAN_Activity_Action ON LEAN_Activity.ID = LEAN_Activity_Action.ActivityID INNER JOIN
                     LEAN_Aktivity_Status ON LEAN_Activity_Action.Status = LEAN_Aktivity_Status.ID


WHERE 
(
Lean_Activity.[ID] LIKE @SearchParam
OR
Lean_Activity.[Site] LIKE @SearchParam
OR
Lean_Activity.[Area] LIKE @SearchParam
OR
Lean_Activity.[ProcessOwner] LIKE @SearchParam
OR
Lean_Activity.[Activity] LIKE @SearchParam
OR
Lean_Activity.[Description] LIKE @SearchParam
OR
Lean_Activity.[Date] LIKE @SearchParam
)
AND
 (@StatusID IS NULL) OR (LEAN_Aktivity_Status.ID = @StatusID )) as tabel

WHERE status = 0 

ORDER BY ID ASC

END
```